# Laravel stopped sending email (mandrill account)

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, swiftmailer, mandrill

This code was working fine previously and laravel abruptly stopped sending mail since last week. I tried to send mail using swiftmailer separately with same credentials which is also working fine. I have following credentials on `.env` file for mail functionality in laravel-

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=*******
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MANDRILL_SECRET=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

I configured `/config/services.php` and `/config/mail.php` files to.

> There is no error in `Mail::failures()`.
>   what could be the possible reason for such problem.

I can send mail with templates using swiftmailer but it's necessary to figure-out the problem to fix such problems with no time in future.